# How to get "bpy.ops.mesh.select_more()" working for a bmesh?

Tags: selection-tools, bmesh

When I select some meshes of my object by hand or with a script, the selection of some meshes "fades out". With "Select - Select More/Less - More) I can select these mesehs, too. But with a script I created a bmes to select my meshes and `bpy.ops.mesh.select_more()` leads to an error:

```
RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.object.select_more.poll() failed, context is incorrect
```

Is there an equivalent for this function with a bmesh?

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to update the bmesh with some more parameters:

```
bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me, False, False)
```

See the reference:
https://docs.blender.org/api/2.79/bmesh.html?highlight=update_edit_mesh#bmesh.update_edit_mesh

Answer (score -1):

You may need to put the selected mesh to edit mode,

```
context.view_layer.objects.active = obj
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
# do something here with bmesh
# ...
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
```